# Interpret return value of bash function

Tags: bash, return, exit-code

I would like to interpret the return value of the function `a` in the parent bash.
I want to use `return` to stop an intermediate script in the parent bash.
In this case it means, that test2 shouldn't be executed.
But it doesn't work.
And I don't want to use `exit`, because it stops "everything" in the parent process.

Does exist a solution to do that?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function a {
   return 1
}

echo "test1"
a
echo "test2"
```

Output:

```
test1
test2
```

The output should be just

```
test1
```

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by "parent bash", "intermediate script", or "parent process".  I see only one script in your example, and each run will be performed by one shell process.  The only other processes involved would be (maybe) for running the two `echo` commands.

Comment: I'm also not following how and why `exit` does not provide a solution, and maybe also *where* it does not provide a solution.  Certainly, changing the the `return 1` to `exit` in function `a` would give you the output you're looking for.  What use do you imagine for `a` where that change would not produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
#!/bin/bash

a() {
   return 1
}

echo "test1"
if ! a; then
  echo "test2"
fi
```

Or for short

```
echo "test1"
a || echo "test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `set -e` can do what you want :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

function a {
   return 1
}

echo "test1"
a
echo "test2"
```

`set -e` might be a "bad idea" : https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises